# How would I find what process is called a node.js script?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I work primarily with asp.net/C#/SQL applications, but have been handed a node.js/MongoDB application that I need to support.  The client lost the original developers and I'm trying to figure fix an issue they're having.  Currently I'm trying to find a "process" that runs and checks/makes updates to the database every 60 seconds.  I've found the script that does the checks/updates, but I don't know where it gets called from or how the variables passed to it are getting populated.  Can someone help me find how this "process" works?

So there's a script called eoaBatch.js that reads and writes to the database.  It appears to have an object called api passed to it.  It's that api object that I need to know how it is populated; that seems to be the current problem.  Here's part of the code for eoaBatch.js:

```
exports.task = {

name: 'eoaBatch',
description: 'End of Batch Processor',

queue: 'eoa',

plugins: [],
pluginOptions: [],

frequency: 60 * 1000, // 1 minute

run: function (api, params, next) {

var Auction = mongoose.model('auctions');
var eoaBatch = mongoose.model('eoaBatches');
var eoaProperty = mongoose.model('eoaProperties');
var eoaBid = mongoose.model('eoaBids');
var Property = mongoose.model('properties');
var SubAccounts = mongoose.model('subaccounts');
var eoaAuction = mongoose.model('eoaAuctions');

async.eachSeries(
  api.batches,
  function forEachBatch(batchInfo, callback) {
```

- How do I find out what calls/starts/runs this script?
- How can I find what is in the api object?

Edit:

Here's package.json.  I replaced the project name with PROJ and removed any other identifying information:

```
{
  "name": "PROJ-api",
  "version": "1.8.0",
  "description": "PROJ",
  "keywords": [
    "PROJ"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://www.PROJ.com",
  "bugs": {
    "email": ""
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "author": "",
  "contributors": [
  ],
  "repository": "/PROJ-api",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/.bin/actionhero start",
    "ci-test": "istanbul cover _mocha > test.tap && istanbul report clover",
    "ci-lint": "eslint -f checkstyle . > checkstyle-result.xml; true"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "accounting": "^0.4.1",
    "actionhero": "^12.3.0",
    "async": "^1.5.0",
    "dateformat": "^1.0.12",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "kerberos": "0.0.17",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "mandrill-api": "^1.0.45",
    "mongoose": "^4.2.9",
    "mongoose-datatable": "^1.0.6",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "redis": "^2.4.2",
    "tv4": "^1.2.7",
    "validator": "^4.3.0",
    "ws": "^0.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0-beta4",
    "babel-preset-airbnb": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint": "^1.10.3",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^1.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.11.2",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.1",
    "mocha": "^2.3.4",
    "should": "latest"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.2.0"
  },
  "os": [
    "darwin",
    "linux"
  ],
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: There is a debugger for nodejs applications. It's called NodeInspector. You can set a breakpoint into the function receiving the api object and then inspect the call stack to figure out where it is called and also inspect the api object.

Comment: Can you show the package.json file too ?

Comment: mh-cbon I added package.json.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [background job](http://www.actionherojs.com/docs/#tasks) for a job queue implemented for [ActionHero](http://www.actionherojs.com/)

Your file [creates tasks](http://www.actionherojs.com/docs/#creating-a-task).

From the docs:

- `api`: The actionhero api object
- `params`: An array of parameters that
  the task was enqueued with. This is whatever was passed as the second
  argument to api.tasks.enqueue
- `next`: A callback to call when the task
  is done. This callback is of the type function(error, result).
  Passing an error object will cause the job to be marked as a failure.
  The result is currently not captured anywhere.